# how long should interrupting signal last?

Tags: interrupt

I want to apply the interruption of a program with a RISING signal from a pin. How long should the signal rise to be considered as the interruption?

Comment: What microcontroller are you using? Have you looked up its datasheet on minimum rise / glitch rejection times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If edge or toggle interrupt is selected, pulses that last longer than one clock period will generate an interrupt. Shorter pulses are not recommended to generate an interrupt.

[Source](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega328_P%20AVR%20MCU%20with%20picoPower%20Technology%20Data%20Sheet%2040001984A.pdf) (page 91, chapter 17.2.1 "External Interrupt Control Register A")

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and the substantial link.